# Cloud-init Yaml File for Windows Server VM Deployment in Openstack

Tags: terraform, openstack, windows-server-2022

I want to deploy a couple of windows server instances in OpenStack using terraform, and I need to create a cloud-init yaml file to give permissions to the right group. While there are lots of good resources for Linux, I can't find any template for Windows anywhere.

I'm looking for the equivalent of this cloud-config for Windows:

```
write_files:
  - path: /etc/ssh/groups.allow
    owner: root:root
    permissions: '0600'
    content: |
      GROUP NAME
  - path: /etc/sudoers.d/my-sudo-rules
    owner: root:root
    permissions: '0600'
    content: |
      GROUP NAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Windows doesn't typically run `cloud-init`. Are you certain your windows images have this service installed?

Comment: @larsks Thanks a lot for your reply! I can see you're a senior principal software engineer at RedHat, so I believe you can help me figure out the issue. As you know, there's a customization script section when launching a new instance in Openstack where I copy this cloud-config into for Linux, but I'm not sure what I should do for Windows. When I leave this section blank, I can't log in to the machine as I'm not authorized! So if Windows doesn't run cloud-init, there must be another way to define the group access that I'm not aware of. I'm new to Openstack and not a professional Windows user..

Comment: @larsks I think the server group, in this case, should be the answer, however, I've added that as well (it's the server group that another windows server is using and I also have access to), but on this VM, I still have no access...

Comment: Because the process of customizing a Windows image depends somewhat on how the image was built, the best folks to ask are probably either (a) the people who maintain your openstack environment, or (b) the people responsible for maintaining the Windows image.

Comment: @larsks I see what you mean. Thanks anyways...